# program does nothing when prompted

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote up a program very hastily just to see if I could improve on some old code I had given up on because I couldn't get it to save but now that I have it writing to a .csv file it does nothing. If I try to interact with it while it is running i.e. press 1,2,3,4 then nothing happens, it doesn't even exit with a reason so I can't troubleshoot it. Here is the code, can anyone tell me what I am missing?

```
import pandas as pd 
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

myDict = {"Apples": 150, "Berries": 200, "Bananas": 300, "Oranges": 350}

def menu():
    print("Press 1: To add stock. ")
    print("Press 2: To check stock. ")
    print("press 3: To enter purchase. ")
    print("Press 4: To quit the program. ")
    return input("What would you like to do? ")

run = menu()

while True:
    if run == '1':
        AddStock = input('Product to be added to stock? ')
        Amount = int(input('Quantity of product to be added to stock? '))
        myDict[AddStock] = Amount
        run = menu()

    elif run == '2':
        for key, value in myDict.items():
            print("{}: {}".format(key, value))
        run = menu()

    elif run == '3':
        product = input('What product was sold? ')
        if product in myDict:
                myDict[product] -= 1
        else:
            print("Product is out of stock! ")
        run = menu()

    elif run == '4':
        with open('stock.csv', 'w') as stock:
            writer = csv.writer(stock)
            for key, value in myDict.items():
                writer.writerow([key, value])
                break
```

Comment: well just asking to make sure. did you press enter?

Comment: You're breaking in the loop writing to the csv never prompting for a new input / terminating the while loop so its just going to continously enter the `elif` statement once `run == '4'` opening / writing over and over again

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody's answered this yet... Here's a quick way to fix it. Although, I'd only display the command options once rather than every time.

```
import csv

myDict = {"Apples": 150, "Berries": 200, "Bananas": 300, "Oranges": 350}

def menu():
    print("Press 1: To add stock.")
    print("Press 2: To check stock.")
    print("press 3: To enter purchase.")
    print("Press 4: To quit the program.")
    return input("What would you like to do? ")

run = None
while run != '4':
    run = menu()
    if run == '1':
        AddStock = input('Product to be added to stock? ')
        Amount = int(input('Quantity of product to be added to stock? '))
        myDict[AddStock] = Amount
    elif run == '2':
        for key, value in myDict.items():
            print("{}: {}".format(key, value))

    elif run == '3':
        product = input('What product was sold? ')
        if product in myDict:
            myDict[product] -= 1
        else:
            print("Product is out of stock! ")

    elif run == '4':
        with open('stock.csv', 'w', newline="") as stock:
            writer = csv.writer(stock)
            for key, value in myDict.items():
                writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: I tried this and the same problem is persisting, it will compile but not do anything once prompted.

Comment: Are you entering input.... Because this works and there's nothing that would cause that